# SQL Sum multiple records with the same properties

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to sum up the count of parts in stock. The part has an original part number and an alternate part number. The alternate part number can be used as a replacement for the original part number. I want to be able to sum the count of this part number as well as the alternate all in one under the original part number.

```
partno | qty
------------
  a1      2
  a2      3

partno | altpartno | qty
------------------------
   a1       b1        2
   a2       b2        2
```

Result:

```
partno | qty
-------------
   a1     4
   a2     5
```

Here is my current attempt:

```
    WITH
    on_order as (
    SELECT
    partno,Count(*) 'On Order'
    FROM amos.od_header oh join amos.od_detail od on(od.orderno_i=oh.orderno_i)
    where oh.state='O' and oh.order_type='P'
    GROUP BY partno
    ),
    on_hand as (
    SELECT p.partno 'Partno',SUM(s.qty) 'Qty On Hand'
    FROM amos.part_alternate p WITH (NOLOCK)
           left outer join amos.store s WITH (NOLOCK)  on  p.partno=s.partno or p.altpartno=s.partno
           left outer join amos.location l WITH (NOLOCK) on  s.locationno_i=l.locationno_i
           left outer join amos.location_restriction lr WITH (NOLOCK) on  lr.location_restriction=l.location_restriction
    WHERE l.location_restriction!='1' --Where Location is not restricted
    GROUP BY p.partno
    ),
alternate_on_hand AS (
SELECT p.altpartno,SUM(s.qty) 'AQty On Hand'
    FROM amos.part_alternate p WITH (NOLOCK)
           left outer join amos.store s WITH (NOLOCK)  on  p.altpartno=s.partno or p.altpartno=s.partno
           left outer join amos.location l WITH (NOLOCK) on  s.locationno_i=l.locationno_i
           left outer join amos.location_restriction lr WITH (NOLOCK) on  lr.location_restriction=l.location_restriction
    WHERE l.location_restriction!='1' --Where Location is not restricted
    GROUP BY p.altpartno)

    SELECT oh.Partno,oh.[Qty On Hand],oo.[On Order], aoh.altpartno, aoh.[AQty On Hand]
    FROM on_hand oh join on_order oo on(oo.partno=oh.Partno) join alternate_on_hand aoh on(aoh.altpartno=oh.partno)
```

My issue is I do not know how to aggrgate all partnos properly. My output is like this:

```
partno | qty | altparnto | Aqty
-------------------------------
  A1      2      B1         1
  A1      2      B2         2
```

Currently using SQL Server Management Studio.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get by with a simpler query.  Here is an approach that uses `union all` and `group by`:

```
select partno, sum(qty)
from ((select partno, qty
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select partno, qty
       from table2
      )
     ) t
group by partno;
```

Your query references a lot of tables and columns that you don't mention in your query.  However, this idea should work there as well.

Comment: Worked perfectly, didn't know why I didnt think of it that way haha. Thanks a bunch!